# Setup Certbot XAMPP Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, xampp, certbot

I'm in the trouble on the XAMPP of Ubuntu when during setting up the certbot by following the link:
https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntubionic-apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I solved the issue and wrote the guideline to help you if you're using the XAMPP of Ubuntu.

The main part:

```
sudo certbot --apache-ctl /opt/lampp/bin/apachectl

sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
------------
# Virtual hosts
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts-le-ssl.conf #Add it here
```

The link: https://github.com/oliguo/Server-Certbot-XAMPP-Ubuntu